# LS19-S, what to do with unused inputs>

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, debounce

I am using a LS19-s switch debouncing IC, and the datasheet does not specify what to do with unused inputs. I know for CMOS chips it standard to ground unused inputs and for TTL chips the unused inputs should be pulled high. However, the chips I am working with do not specify if it is CMOS or TTL based. Thanks in advance for any help.

The link to the datasheet: [LS19-S datasheet](https://logiswitch.com/wp-content/uploads/LS10-Series-ICs-Technical-Details.pdf)

Below is the a portion of the circuit I am talking about:
[image: circuit with the LS19-S with unused inputs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As evidenced byboth your circuit and the reference circuit on page 6 of the datasheet, the IC already has internal pullups - the buttons just need to pull an input down, and no external pullup is provided.

According to the datasheet, the internal pullup current (with the switch closed) is between 25 and 200 uA, with a typical value of 120 uA.

As a result, it's fine to leave the inputs unconnected - the pullup will pull the input high without much power dissipation. If you're concerned about significant noise making it onto these pins, you may consider an external pullup for both used and unused pins (since used pins whose switches aren't pressed are also floating)

Comment: If I were to use external pullups, would 10k be fine?

Comment: @ZackeryFleming Yep, 10k sounds reasonable, as long as you aren't super power constrained in your application.